# Json error with xamarin

Tags: android, json, xamarin

My environment is Android and i use Xamarin for do my project.
I have a problem with my connection to server, for that i use Json my error is :

```
`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String. Path '', line 1, position 2. at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load`
```

so my code app side is :

```
public async Task Login (string user_email, string user_password)
{
var content = new Dictionary<string, string> { {
"user_email",
user_email
},
{
"user_password",
user_password
}
};
String str = await ProcessPOST ("/api/login", content);
JObject data = JObject.Parse (str);

        if (data ["success"] != null)
            return (string)data ["success"];
        throw new Exception ((string)data ["error"]);
    }
```

and server side is :

So login

```
public function login() {
if ($this->method == "POST") {
if ($this->_data("user_email") && $this->_data("user_password")) {
$u_dao = new UserDAO();
$users = $u_dao->executeSelect("WHERE user_email = :user_email", array("user_email" => $this->_data("user_email")));

            if (!isset($users[0]))
                return $this->_response(array("error" => "User not found"), 403);

            $user = $users[0];
            if ($user && crypt($this->_data("user_password"), $user->user_password) == $user->user_password) {
                $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
                $user->user_token = $token;
                $u_dao->update($user);
                return $this->_response(array("success" => $token));
            }
            return $this->_response(array("error" => "Bad login"), 403);
        }
        return $this->_response(array("error" => "Missing data"), 500);
    }
    return $this->_response(array("error" => "Wrong method"), 405);
}
```

and code of _response

```
protected function _response($data, $status = 200) {
header("HTTP/1.1 " . $status . " " . $this->_requestStatus($status));
return json_encode($data);
}
```

and now of _requestStatus

```
private function _requestStatus($code) {
$status = array(
200 => 'OK',
403 => 'Forbidden',
404 => 'Not Found',
405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
500 => 'Internal Server Error',
);
return ($status[$code]) ? $status[$code] : $status[500];
}
```

and when i try to connect my web service is online , but i forget to said when i have error like "Missing Data" i haven't error of JObject but when i have success i have error.

so i show to all two str one of error:

```
"{\"error\":\"Missing data\"}"
```

and one of succes:

```
"''{\"success\":\"db035db78a9f1e64d71c83bcbb45ffa5\"}"
```

i want to said thanks to all people which help me . And i'm sorry for my bad english but i'm french .

i hope to be clear but if u have question u can ask them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any necessary use for Json.net here. I would simplify and just check if the response contains "success" or "error".